# Android Instrumentaion: How do I go back to a previously launched Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, instrumentation

I'm currently running automation tests using an app that uses multiple Activity for displaying each screen.

Is there anyway to go back to a previously launched Activity while running an Instrumentation test? Currently, when I use sendKeyDownUpSync( KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);, this forces my test to exit, rather than go back to the previous Activity.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Jin

Answer (score 6):

You could try calling the `finish()` method on the Activity you wish to close.

Answer (score 1):

Cool. `finish()` works well :) Unless,of course, Android Runtime doesn't kill the previous activity to free resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use method to do this as well. 
Thia is not recommended way to do but below is the code that can be usefull for you.

```
public void launchActivityCurrent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        System.out.println("Inside Launch  Activity current");
                      intent.setClassName("YourpackageName","Activity you want to launch");
                      For ex:
        intent.setClassName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList");
        Context c = currentContext();
        c.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I use robotium and i dont call instrumentation again so i use this way to launch in application activity.
I hope this is also usefull for you.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried `onBackPressed()`?
Refer [Go back to previous activity](http://myandroidnote.blogspot.com/2011/04/go-back-to-previous-activity.html) for details